# Question on the transversality between sections

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $M^n$ be a differentiable manifold and $\pi\colon E\to M$ is $n$-dimensional vector bundle over $M$.

We have a zero section $s\colon M\to E$ of $\pi$.

How can I make a section $s'$ which is trnasversal to $s$? (i.e., $s'$ vanishes $s$ finitely many times.)

(In some text, it seems even possible to make $s$ and $s'$ are isotopic.)

I need this to interpret the euler class of $\pi$, $\chi(\pi)$ as an algebraic intersection number of $s$ and $s'$.

Are there anybody who can give me any references?

Comment: I'd suggest Guillemin and Pollack, Differential topology.  You are looking for the Transversality theorem.  (Also see wikipedia for the statement http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversality_theorem)